# How custom template implement in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am new in Opencart, I have installed Opencart 2.3.0.2 in my xampp server.
I have a custom html template. How I implement it in Opencart ?
can I use the template in same store(opencart default) or another ?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Copy - paste default theme, rename it to your theme name, enable there in admin panel

Comment: @Justinas : Actually this is a custom template , I have html,css,js files, images and fonts folders. How I paste it ?

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-introduction--cms-21786), you will have to go through each page an adapt it to work with your "template"

Answer (score 0):

Make copies…

To start with copy the default folder found in
upload/catalog/view/theme/default
to a new folder in the same directory. Name it “mytheme“.

Then copy the theme_default.php file in
upload/admin/controller/extension/theme
and place it in same directory. Name it “mytheme.php“.

- Rename the class to (line 2):

ControllerExtensionThemeMyTheme
+ Replace all “theme_default” text to “mytheme“. Yes there are a lot (197).

Copy the theme_default.tpl in
upload/admin/view/template/extension/theme
and place it in the same directory. Name it “mytheme.tpl“.

- Replace all “theme_default” text to “mytheme“. (48)

Copy theme_default.php in
upload/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme
and place it in the same directory. Name it “mytheme.php“.

- Set the new theme’s title in heading_title (line 3) to “My Theme”.

Finally for the thumnail image to show correctly in store settings rename default.png to mytheme.png in
upload/catalog/view/theme/mytheme/image
Now go into your Administration > Extensions > Extensions and select Themes in “Choose the extension type”. You should be seeing your new theme. Install it with the green (+) button and edit it to enable it. Also ensure you set the correct theme directory whilst editing the theme!

Then in System > Settings edit your store to use your new theme.

That should do it. You can now go ahead and start chopping and changing the default theme.

Comment: Thank you very much